Excel If OR daylight savings
I am trying to add an OR statement into this however cant seem to get it.
The formula works when the sysdate is between the DLS starts and DLS Ends date range (returns Yes).
However I need to add the following years also. As the Sysdate is NOW(), it needs to change to No when its not in the date range then turn back to Yes on 1/10/2025 till 06/04/2026.


Are you trying to determine if a date is between two other dates? =IF(AND(date>=startDLS,date<endDLS),"Yes","No").  Adjust the cell references as needed.

Hi Michal, yes which is working at the moment. I just need to combine all the other years so it check the other dates each year as well.

So put the formula in the first cell and copy it down.

You could also use a single dynamic formula =IF((I2>=L2:L5)*(I2<=M2:M5),"Yes","No")

no row headers in screens making our lives tougher (unnecessarily)

This formula will return the result in one cell for all the dates with the OR function
=IF(OR(($I$2>=L2:L5)*($I$2<=M2:M5)),"YES","NO")

